# How do I use the fadeIn and fadeOut effect in CakePHP on change event?

Tags: jquery, cakephp, cakephp-2.6

I am using jshelper (jquery) to populate the dropdown list with 'change' event in parent dropdown.
And This is working fine.
Effects fadeIn And fadeOut not working.
i'm confused with the effects.
Here is parent and child drop down.

```
<div class="form-group">
                                    <label class="h5">Category</label>
                                    <div class="advance-search-form-control">
                                        <?php echo $this->Form->input('catagory',array(
                                            'class' => 'form-control',
                                            'options'=>$catagory,
                                            'div' => false,
                                            'label' => false,
                                            'type' =>'select',
                                            'empty' =>'--select--',
                                            'id' => 'catagory',
                                        ));  ?>
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                                <div class="form-group">
                                    <label class="h5" id="c_label" hidden>Subcatagory</label>
                                    <div id="c_show" hidden>
                                        <div class="advance-search-form-control">
                                            <?php echo $this->Form->input('subcatagory',
                                                array('class'=>'user_login form-control',                            
                                                    'id'=>'subcatagory',
                                                    'div'=>false,
                                                    'label'=>false,
                                                    'type' => 'select',
                                                ));
                                            ?>
                                        </div>
                                    </div>
                                </div>
```

Here is jquery (JsHelper) code for triggring event and show effects.

```
<?php
$this->Js->get('#catagory')->event('change',
 $this->Js->request(array(
    'controller'=>'subcatagories',
    'action'=>'getByCat'
), array(
    'update'=>'#subcatagory',
    'async' => true,
    'method' => 'post',
    'dataExpression'=>true,
    'data'=> $this->Js->serializeForm(array(
        'isForm' => true,
        'inline' => true,
        'before' => $this->Js->get('#wait')->effect('fadeOut', array('buffer' => false)),
        'success' => $this->Js->get('#wait')->effect('fadeIn', array('buffer' => false))
    ))
))
```

);
?>

And Simple div:

```
<div id="wait" style="display: none">wait...</div>
```

Any Help ? Thanks in advance.